# Limit a counter for votes with PHP session?

Tags: php, session, counter

I am trying to get a limiter for a counter of votes on products from my database. As of now, the vote-counter are endless, rendering the possibility to vote on a product several times. The sites has a login function, and therefore also sessions.

What I'm thinking is some sort of counter that locks the ability to vote on a product more than just one time for each user, and only leaves the opportunity to vote the other way (vote down if voted up and other way around).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have 3 Tables in your database:

```
Product(Id, Name, ...)
User(Id, Name, EMail, Password)
Vote(Id, ProductId, UserId, Type) // Where Type is Upvote/Downvote/Whatever
```

When a user votes you just make an entry into the `Vote` table and set the ProductId, UserId and of course the type of the vote. This way you can always check if a user already voted on a product.

You can even make a unique constraint for `(ProductId, UserID)` on the `Vote` table.

Comment: Thank for your answer halfdan! This solution did struck my mind earlier, and also is the one solution I'm going with if sessions can't do the job. It's just that I was curious to see if I was way out of league thiking sessions could do something like this...

Comment: In fact you could use sessions for it, but note that sessions are bound to a cookie on the client side. A user can easily remove the cookie ad make you loose all data about the session. Without any authorization you cannot make sure that a user votes only once.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. Didn't think of that, and it might be a problem in the end. I'm gonna go with the earlier solution.